# Getting error when running Invoke-AppWrappingTool with Android App Wrapping Tool

Tags: android

I am unable to wrap my Android app using [Wrapping tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/app-wrapper-prepare-android).

When I run the following command:

```
Invoke-AppWrappingTool -InputPath C:\...... -OutputPath C:\output.... -KeyStorePath ......
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Application wrapping in progress. App Wrapping Tool Version:
1.0.1933.1
    Failed to package app.
            com.microsoft.intune.mam.apppackager.utils.AppPackagerException:
Failed to update this app's supported SDK versi
    ons.
                    com.microsoft.intune.mam.apppackager.utils.YamlManifestUtils.updateAppSupportedSdkRange(YamlManifestUtil
    s.java:324)
                    com.microsoft.intune.mam.apppackager.v2.V2WrapperAgent.wrapManifest(V2WrapperAgent.java:86)
                    com.microsoft.intune.mam.apppackager.AbstractWrapperAgent.wrap(AbstractWrapperAgent.java:68)

com.microsoft.intune.mam.apppackager.AppPackager.packageApp(AppPackager.java:132)
                   com.microsoft.intune.mam.apppackager.PackagerMain.mainInternal(PackagerMain.java:198)

com.microsoft.intune.mam.apppackager.PackagerMain.main(PackagerMain.java:56)
            com.microsoft.intune.mam.apppackager.utils.AppPackagerException: This
app's target SDK is above the MAM target S
    DK. Please upgrade to the newest version of the App Wrapping Tool.
                    com.microsoft.intune.mam.apppackager.utils.YamlManifestUtils.updateAppSupportedSdkRange(YamlManifestUtil
    s.java:305)
                    com.microsoft.intune.mam.apppackager.v2.V2WrapperAgent.wrapManifest(V2WrapperAgent.java:86)
                    com.microsoft.intune.mam.apppackager.AbstractWrapperAgent.wrap(AbstractWrapperAgent.java:68)
                    com.microsoft.intune.mam.apppackager.AppPackager.packageApp(AppPackager.java:132)
                    com.microsoft.intune.mam.apppackager.PackagerMain.mainInternal(PackagerMain.java:198)
                   com.microsoft.intune.mam.apppackager.PackagerMain.main(PackagerMain.java:56)
    The application could not be wrapped.
```

I am using `targetSdkVersion 26` & `compileSdkVersion 25`.

Answer (score 0):

It reads: `Please upgrade to the newest version of the App Wrapping Tool.`

... which can be found [here](https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/intune-app-wrapping-tool-android/releases/).

Answer (score 0):

Your  targetSdkVersion 26 & compileSdkVersion 25.however it should be greater than 28 which is 9 or above. then it will work[image]